# Solving $A + B\sin(2C) = (G+LC)\sin(A-C)$ for $C$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a trigonometric equation, as follows:

> $$A + B\sin(2C) = (G+LC)\sin(A-C)$$
>   where $A$, $B$, $G$, $L$ are known constants.

I have no idea for solve it. Please help me!

Comment: The variable $C$ is unknown?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The equation looks a bit strange. Some context would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a trancendental equation in $C$. I am afraid that only numerical methods would do the job. Can you provide values for $A,B,G,L$ ?

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard, I want to find the root C for this equation.

Comment: Dear Claude and Arnaud! This equation is transformed by multiple steps. These values are constants